# Crystal Reports 2008, PDF export, Chinese Characters are not visible for Arial Font

Tags: crystal-reports, report

We have windows application with C#, using vs2008.
In this application we are using Crystal report 10.5, with Arial Font as application font.

While exporting to PDF, its not showing Chinese characters.

It seems that using font "MS UI Gothic", we can see the chinese character in pdf file.

But as per requirement we must use Arial Font.

Please let us know if any one has any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved issue by following steps:

- First export the report in RTF format.
- Use office interop to convert RTF to PDF format.